# Why have multiple threads on a server

Tags: events, threadpool

I am creating an server to send data to many persistent sockets. I have chosen the REACTOR design pattern which suggests having multiple threads to send data to along sockets.

I cannot understand what is better:
- To have one thread to send all of the data to sockets
- Or have a couple of threads to send data across the sockets.

The way I see it is that I have 2 cores. So I can only do two things at once. Whcih would mean I have 1 worker thread and 1 thread to send data?

Why would it be better to have mulitple threads to send data when you suffer context switching between the threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See documentation on thttpd as to why single threaded non [***blocking IO is good***](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/notes.html).  Indeed it makes good sense for static files.

If you are doing CGI however, you may have a script that runs for a long time.  It's nicer to not hold up all the quicker simpler traffic, especially if the script has an infinite-loop bug in it and is to eventually be killed anyway!  With threads ***the average response time experienced by users will be better*** - if some of the requests are very time consuming.

If the files being served come from disk and are not in main memory already, a similar argument can be used.